# Need Bootstrap's great collection, but need more flexibility

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, styles, css-frameworks

I find Bootstrap insufficiently flexible. For example there's not a straightforward way to change `font` or `line-height` properties. I want a one-line method to change these properties.

What else can I use similar to Bootstrap (that I'm sure will not be as rich)? I just need some style collections that are flexible for those kinds of changes.

Comment: Cant you just override those properties?

Comment: Huh, I thought for sure you could change these on the [Customization Page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html). I guess I'll have to look deeper.

Comment: @PeterRowell, oh, where was the `Customize` button?! I'd been so angry when posting the question! So please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change all of the typography values (and pretty much everything else) on the [Customize Page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html). The links are in the toolbar at the top of most pages of the Bootstrap site.